# T-SQL execute Trigger on Update and on IF condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm currently working on a stored procedure in T-SQL on SQL Server 2014.

I'm looking for a way or would like to know if it's possible to execute a Trigger on the Update of a table, but only if an if-condition is true.

```
-- table project
--CREATE TABLE [MySchema].[Project] (
--  ProjectId INT
--  , Label VARCHAR(1000)
--);

-- trigger
CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdate_Project
    ON [MySchema].[Project]
    FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE ([Label])
        PRINT 'Label updated, version 1'
END
GO

-- stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE [MySchema].[SaveProject]
    -- Importing Parameters
    @IsVersion BIT
    , @Label VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @IsVersion = 0 -- don't execute trigger
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [A]
        SET [A].Label = 'lorem ipsum text'
        FROM [MySchema].[Project] AS [A]
        WHERE [A].ProjectId = '1'
    END


    IF @IsVersion  = 1 -- execute Trigger
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [A]
        SET [A].Label = @Label
        FROM [MySchema].[Project] AS [A]
        WHERE [A].ProjectId = '1'
    END

END
```

What do you think, is it possible to somehow execute the trigger if @IsVersion = 1 ?

How would you solve this... Thank you very much!!

Comment: If the version is set to 1, would the label ever be set to 'lorem ipsum text'? If not, check that on the inserted in the trigger to see if it needs to go any further.

Comment: Thanks, good point to check the inserted in the trigger!! ...To be honest, the model is a bit more complex. In my real application, i need to update another Id in the ProjectTable, when a new Version gets created... this is just a simple example :) thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Session Context](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189252(v=sql.105).aspx) when two pieces of procedural T-SQL need a means to convey information between them but they are not directly calling each other (and so parameters are not an option).

Note that this is in no way secure, so it shouldn't be used to make security decisions - *any* piece of code can choose to change the Session Context information before making a change that causes the trigger to fire.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgUpdate_Project
    ON [MySchema].[Project]
    FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF CONTEXT_INFO() = 0x56455253494F4E30 RETURN
    IF UPDATE ([Label])
        PRINT 'Label updated, version 1'
END
```

And

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MySchema].[SaveProject]
    -- Importing Parameters
    @IsVersion BIT
    , @Label VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @IsVersion = 0 -- don't execute trigger
    BEGIN
        SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x56455253494F4E30
        UPDATE [A]
        SET [A].Label = 'lorem ipsum text'
        FROM [MySchema].[Project]
        WHERE [A].ProjectId = 1
    END


    IF @IsVersion  = 1 -- execute Trigger
    BEGIN
        SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x56455253494F4E31
        UPDATE [A]
        SET [A].Label = @Label
        FROM [MySchema].[Project]
        WHERE [A].ProjectId = 1
    END

END
```

Comment: this works very fine for my needs! thanks a lot for the superb solution!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the trigger when executing the code for @IsVersion = 0 and after the update enable it again.

```
IF @IsVersion = 0 -- don't execute trigger
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[Project] DISABLE TRIGGER trgUpdate_Project;

    UPDATE [A]
    SET [A].Label = 'lorem ipsum text'
    FROM [MySchema].[Project]
    WHERE [A].ProjectId = 1

    ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[Project] ENABLE TRIGGER trgUpdate_Project;
END
```

Comment: That's a bad idea - what's meant to happen when there are two simultaneous calls to this procedure, one with `@IsVersion` set to `0`, the other with `1`? Disabling a trigger is a *global* setting.